# Floating image on a background image float towards left of screen on high resolution

Tags: html, css, image

I got a page which has a background image and some floating images over that. These images are linked to the background image that is why i want to show the floating image on the exact point on background (Will be cleared in screenshot below).
[Screenshot](http://screencast.com/t/MMXag4a3Cw6)

As you can see in above image image named religion is above a temple in background image and so the people and safari but the mail problem is expedition image which on resolution change floats to left and replaced from the top of the mountain peak in background image.
Please help me to get this working on all resolution.

[Demo Link](http://radicosys.com/hs_new/ladakh.html)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the expedition image is changing its position in relation to the actual page instead of the background image like all of the other images are. You could try putting all of the images inside a div, so when the page resizes it changes the size of the div (if you are using %'s to define the dimensions of the div). This might keep all of the images placed where you want them to stay.